# Can i use episerver CMS as identity provider for SSO using SAML?

Tags: episerver, episerver-7

I need to do SSO between episerver CMS and Liferay CMS using SAML. I know that LifeRay can act both as Service Provider as well as Identity Provider. I want to know that can Episerver CMS also act as Identity provider as well as service provider?

Answer (score 1):

EPiServer uses the standard ASP.NET provider model for authorization/authentication, and by default ships with Windows and SQL membership and role providers for forms authentication.

In other words, I'm not aware of anything particular OOTB that would enable SAML SSO. But seeing as there's nothing EPiServer-specific about authentication, you should be able to add SSO support just as you would for a vanilla ASP.NET app.